MIPS instructions
what does the following two MIPS INSTRUCTIONS mean >>>>> lw $t1,offset_value($t2) (or) sw $t1,offset_value ($t2)
The above two instructions are MIPS instructions....What is offset value and to what should we add the offset value what is actually done here in processor while executing it. May I get the answer in an elaborate way....

These are data transfer instructions.  They access memory and transfer data between memory and a CPU register.
First, an effective address is computed, then memory is read or written.
lw reads from memory.  It is a 4-byte access, so 4 consecutive bytes of memory are transferred to the target register.
sw writes into memory.  It is also a 4-byte access, so 4 consecutive bytes of memory are written with the contents of the target register.
Both are I-Type instructions, meaning the instruction encodes 4 fields:
opcode:6 source-register:5 target-register:5 immediate:16

The effective address is computed by (1) sign extending the 16-bit immediate to 32-bits, then adding to the contents of the value held in the designated source-register.  The 4 addresses accessed start with the computed effective address and then consecutive byte addresses (i.e. e.a. +1, +2, and +3).  lw updates the target-register to hold the value obtained from memory; while sw updates memory to hold the value held in the target-register.
When multiple bytes are accessed in one instruction, an ordering of the bytes must be chosen, and for MIPS it can be either of the two popular orderings, big or little endian.  The choice of which depends on the particular processor or the simulator, and generally cannot be changed dynamically.
For MIPS on 4-byte memory access, the effective address must be a multiple of 4; this is called alignment and this requirement makes the hardware somewhat simpler.  An unaligned access will fault rather than succeed.  Further, certain memory locations are out of bounds even if aligned (usually address zero for example), so we should take care to only access memory that has been validly obtained (e.g. global variables, stack variables, heap variables, and memory mapped IO locations when applicable as with bare metal or the operating system itself).
These instructions are used as follows:

To access stack-based local memory using the variable's offset in the stack as the immediate, and the stack pointer as the base register.

For expressions like p->f in C, which is accessing a field f of an object referred to by pointer, p.  Here the pointer value (referring to the object) is placed in the source register, and the offset to f from the beginning of the object is used as the immediate.

To access global variables, where a multi-instruction sequence ends with lw or sw to load or store a 4-byte global variable.  Here the specific offset is chosen by combination of compiler/linker to access the specific global variable.

And finally, with an offset/immediate value of 0 (the additive identity) we can do a simple dereference of a pointer as we would see in C as in ... = *p or *p = ....



I am a beginner in computer architecture. As a need for my further  clarification regarding assembly language and its implementation, may I know if a  processor is designed after preparing an ISA(instruction set architecture) or ISA is prepared after designing an optimized processor...
